# Decimal Step Unit Admin Orders

Tags: ajax, function, woocommerce

I am using this code in my child theme to allow the user to update the product quantities in decimal units from the backend when creating or editing a woocommerce order.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
      if(is_admin()){
    return 0.1;
    }
```

This works in the backend and lets me edit product quantities in decimal units. However, because one of the plugins I'm using makes a wordpress AJAX request on the front end, the is_admin() is returning true on the front end as well and I need it not to. I tried modifying the code as per below to check for the is doing AJAX condition:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'nsk_allow_decimal');
function nsk_allow_decimal($val) {
      if(is_admin() && ( ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) || ! DOING_AJAX )){
    return 0.1;
    }
```

This works on the front-end so that the 0.1 isn't returned. And it works when editing an order from the backend. But it doesn't work when creating a new order manually from the backend because of the is doing AJAX condition.
I've tried to find ways to remove the is doing AJAX condition and instead trying to target the actual order pages and I had partial success with new orders but not with edited orders.

```
function cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_step( $step, $product ) {
    if (is_admin() && (is_order_create_page() || is_order_edit_page())){
        $step = 0.1;
    }
    return $step;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'cw_woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 10, 2 );

function is_order_create_page() {
    global $pagenow;
    return $pagenow == 'post-new.php' && isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'shop_order';
}

function is_order_edit_page() {
    global $pagenow;
    return $pagenow == 'post.php' && isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit' && isset($_GET['post']) && 'shop_order' == get_post_type($_GET['post']);
}
```

The above code works for the front end (in that it doesn't apply the decimal step). And it allows me to save a decimal value for a product in an edit order but won't then let me click the update button for the order. And it doesn't work at all when creating a new order. I've searched online for days and can't find anything.

Does anyone know how to get this to work when creating and editing orders from the backend without using the is doing AJAX condition? Or an alternative to is_admin so it doesn't return true for front end pages where an ajax request is made?